# Access policies are not set correctly to function apps in deployment slots

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have the following ARM template for deploying Azure Function App and add key vault access policies to this function app:

```
module functionAppTemplate_F 'functionApp.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppTemplate-F'
  params: {    
  }
  dependsOn: [
    servicePlanTemplate
  ]
}

module functionAppSlotTemplate_F 'functionAppSlot.bicep' = {
  name: 'functionAppSlotTemplate-F'
  params: {    
  }
  dependsOn: [
    functionAppTemplate_F
  ]
}

module DataKeyVaultPoliciesTemplate 'keyVaultAccessPolicy.bicep' = {
  name: 'DataKeyVaultPoliciesTemplate'
  scope: resourceGroup(dataKeyVaultResourceGroup)
  params: {
    name: dataKeyVaultName
    policies: [
      {
        objectId: functionAppTemplate_F.outputs.msi
        permissions: [
          'get'
          'set'
          'list'
        ]
      }
{
        objectId: functionAppSlotTemplate_F.outputs.msi
        permissions: [
          'get'
          'set'
          'list'
        ]
      }
    ]
    tenantId: tenantId
  }
  dependsOn: [
    functionAppTemplate_F
    functionAppSlotTemplate_F 
  ]
}
```

```
resource accessPolicies 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2016-10-01' = {
  name: '${name}/add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [for item in policies: {
      tenantId: tenantId
      objectId: item.objectId
      permissions: {
        secrets: item.permissions
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

On running this, the access policies are not set correctly and the deployment is failing. What am I missing? I started noticing this after updating the template to add a staging slot and add key vault access policies to staging slot.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is related to managed identity ?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are still facing the issue. If yes can confirm if the shared is the full bicep template?